# JavaScript/JQuery how can I get id of the caller to the new view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two  links and both links redirect to the same new url (View) .

But depending on which href link was clicked, I need to show or hide buttons on the new view.

My question is there a way to know the id of the event/caller that redirected to current/new view?

I tried looking into jquery history method but wasn't successful.

Thank you

Comment: You can use [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for this purpose.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research and if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Query String by implementing something like the one below.

```
<a href="index.html?link=link_1" class="link_1 links">Link 1</a>
<a href="index.html?link=link_2" class="link_2 links">Link 2</a>
```

Above we have 2 links and below I've added some CSS for those links

```
.links {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hide-link {
    display: none;
}
```

`.hide-link` will be used to hide the currently clicked links.

And below is where the miracle happens.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //the magic is here.. the below code will get the current URL
    const clickedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
    //this will get the current clicked link between link_1 & link_2 as indicated in my buttons
    let link = clickedUrl.searchParams.get('link')
    //then we add the '.hide-link' link that's currently clicked
    $('.'+link).addClass('hide-link')
})
```

This is general idea but I'm sure from this you can be able to have exactly what you are looking for.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9ra8xp4/) with `link_1` as the current link selected.